# Minimal Diophantine equations to define all subsets of {1,...,N}

Tags: modular-arithmetic, diophantine-equations

Let $N\in\mathbb{N}$, $[N] = \{0,\dots,N-1\}$. There are $2^N$ subsets of $[N]$, so $N$ bits are enough to define a subset $S\subseteq[N]$, e.g. by [Ackermann encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BIT_predicate).

On the other side each $S\subseteq[N]$ can be defined by a Diophantine equation $\phi_S(k,a_k,\dots, a_1, a_0)$:

$n \in S \leftrightarrow (a_k n^k + \dots + a_1 n^1)\mod N = a_0$

How can some numbers $K, A_K, \dots, A_0$ be choosen, such that every subset $S\subseteq[N]$ has a Diophantine equation $\phi(k,a_k,\dots a_0)$ defining it with

- $k \leq K$
- $a_i < 2^{A_i}$

Let $\Phi(K,A_K,\dots,A_0)$ be the set of all Diophantine equations fullfilling these conditions.

It is obvious that $\Sigma A_i $ has to be $\geq N$ while otherwise not all of the $2^N$ subsets could be defined.

So the question is more precisely:

> What are the minimal numbers $K,M$ such that there are $A_K,\dots,A_0$
>   with $\Sigma A_i = M$ and $\Phi(K,A_K,\dots,A_0)$ defines all subsets
>   of $[N]$?

Might $M$ be as small as $N$? If not so: how can I determine it?

For a given minimal $M$, may there be more than one $(K,A_K,\dots,A_0)$ with $\Sigma A_i = M$ such that $\Phi(K,A_K,\dots,A_0)$ defines all subsets of $[N]$?

Comment: um, not every subset $S$ of $\Bbb Z/N\Bbb Z$ is the zero set of a polynomial. For example, $\{0;1\} \subset \Bbb Z/4\Bbb Z$ can't be defined by a Diophantine equation mod $4$.

Comment: How can I see that? How do I prove it?

Comment: What's wrong with $(2x^3 + x^2 + x)\text{mod}4=0$?

Comment: hmm right, sorry I messed up this one. I still expect that you can't have every subset of $\Bbb Z/p^n\Bbb Z$ for some $n$ but right now idk and there is an easier alternative. modulo $6$, you can't have $\{1;5\}$. If $f(1) = f(5) = 0$ then $f(4) = f(3) = 0$ too because of the Chinese Remainder Theorem

Comment: What about $(5x^3+x^2+x)\text{mod}6=1$? This holds for 1 and 5, but not for 0,2,3,4, does it?

Comment: dangit xD no more commenting late at night. I think I meant $\{0 ; 1 \}$ ? If $f(0) = f(1) = 0$ mod $6$ then $f(3) = f(1) = 0$ mod $2$ and $f(3) = f(0) = 0$ mod $3$ so $f(3)=0$ mod $6$. I think ? I'm not sure of anything anymore

Comment: Do you agree with the new modality of not publishing separately the answers? I do not. With the sizeable number of questions, each answer given, not many people will read.

Comment: I have noticed that you have offered a bounty but received no answer. Maybe you might be interesting in my effort to collect somewhere unresolved bounties. For details see [meta](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/23647/could-list-of-unresolved-past-bounties-be-useful/23715#23715) and [this chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/43020/2016/7/26).